# Update a single object property in an array of objects based on the current value with redux

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability

Within my state, I have an array of objects that have a few descriptive properties, a quantity, and a unique id. The data within this object comes back from an API response, and within my action creator, I check the state to see if it exists already and if so dispatch an increment action for my reducer. This is what my action creator looks like:

```
export const getProductDetails = upc => (dispatch, getState) => {
const state = getState();
const products = state.table.products;
if (_find(products, upc) !== undefined) {
  dispatch({ type: INCREMENT_QUANTITY, payload: upc });
} else {
axios
  .post(<--POST TO ENDPOINT-->) }
  })
  .then(res => {
    dispatch({ type: POST_UPC, payload: res.data });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    errorHandler(dispatch, err.response, AUTH_ERROR);
  });
 }
};
```

My reducer for this case looks is structured as so:

```
case INCREMENT_QUANTITY:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map(product => {
      action.payload === product.upc
        ? { ...product, quantity: product.quantity + 1 }
        : product;
    })
  };
```

I based this reducer logic from this 
[this excellent response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629785), but for some reason when the action is dispatched, the duplicate product is overwritten as `null` instead of incrementing the quantity as expected. I'm still trying to learn redux right now, so forgive my ignorance. Ideally, I'd like to avoid bringing in a library or package just to increment a value. What exactly am I missing within my reducer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything in your `map` callback, you're creating a block thus you don't get the intended result. Instead, omit the brackets `{ … }`:

```
products: state.products.map(product => 
  action.payload === product.upc
    ? { ...product, quantity: product.quantity + 1 }
    : product;
);
```

This will use arrow function syntax to implicitly return the result of the ternary operator.

Comment: Perfect! I knew I was missing something small within that map function. So now the object within the array doesn't become `null`, but the quantity field stays static across multiple dispatched calls to increment that field. Is there something I'm missing there as well?

Comment: @ChristianTodd Perhaps you meant `action.payload.upc`? Could your provide the dispatched action?

Comment: I updated my original question to contain my entire action creator. Hopefully that will be more clear.

Comment: @ChristianTodd That might be beyond the scope of the initial question. Maybe asking a new one with all the details will get fresh eyes and an exact answer.