# Redux/react. How to change some element in the array of Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I'm working on understanding of how we can change some `button` `id` in array `iteams.buttons`. I read off docs and also this great post [How to update single value inside specific array item in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628774/how-to-update-single-value-inside-specific-array-item-in-redux) . But in my case it does not help, because I have  some other error, that I cannot catch.

I make a several tests and what I have:

1. The `action` send data to `reducer` normally, because in `FORK_TODO` I track it via `console.log` and it display `true` (as I wanted).
2. After rerender first time by case `FORK_TODO` - it gives me the non-changed array of `iteams` without any changes for some `state.iteams.buttons.id` that will change own `done` prop by the condition of the same `id` and `action.id`.
3. After all next rerenders by case `FORK_TODO` - it destroys my array of buttons, makes it without any objects, just with array of `undefined`'s .

So, I think that the problem in my construction of `FORK_TODO` `reducer`, but I cannot figure out where...

Please, help if someone see my stupid mistake in this case :(

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TODO, FORK_TODO, ADDED_BUTTON, TOGGLE_BUTTON, EDIT_TODO, DELETE_TODO, FILTER_TODO_UP, FILTER_TODO_DOWN } from '../Variables/Variables'

const initialState = {
    iteams: {
        todos:[],
        buttons:[]
    }
}

function TodoApp(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initialState;
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                iteams: {
                    todos: [
                        ...state.iteams.todos, 
                        {
                            id: action.id,
                            text: action.text,
                        }
                    ],
                    buttons: [
                        ...state.iteams.buttons, 
                        {
                            id: action.id,
                            text: action.text,
                            done: 'false'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        case FORK_TODO:
        console.log(state.iteams.buttons[0].id === parseInt(action.id)); // return "true"!!
            return {
                iteams: {
                    todos: [
                        ...state.iteams.todos
                    ],
                    buttons: [
                        state.iteams.buttons.map(button => {
                            (button.id === parseInt(action.id)) 
                            ? {...state.iteams.buttons, done: action.text}
                            : state.iteams.buttons
                        })
                    ]
                }
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}



export default TodoApp
```

**UPD**:
It work now:

```
    case FORK_TODO:
       return {
            iteams: {
                todos: [
                    ...state.iteams.todos
                ],
                buttons: [
                  ...state.iteams.buttons.map(button => {
                    return (button.id === parseInt(action.id)) ?
                        {...state.iteams.button, done: !button.done} : button
                  })
                ]
            }
        }
```

**But!** when we update the `done` in some `button`, it rewrite all props of this obj. Why? In off docs this way of changing single value rewrite only `this` obj `value`, not the values of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    case FORK_TODO:
    console.log(state.iteams.buttons[0].id === parseInt(action.id));
    console.log("- action.id -");
    console.log(action.id);
    console.log(" - state.iteams.buttons[0] - ");
    console.log(state.iteams.buttons[0]);
    console.log(" - state.iteams - ");
    console.log(state.iteams);
        const newState = {
            iteams: {
                todos: [
                    ...state.iteams.todos
                ],
                buttons: [
                   ...state.iteams.buttons.map(button => {
                    return (button.id === parseInt(action.id)) ?
                        {...state.iteams.button, done: action.text} : button
                  })
                ]
              }
            }
            console.log(" - newState.iteams.buttons[0] - ");
            console.log(newState.iteams.buttons[0]);
            console.log(" - newState.iteams - ");
            console.log(newState.iteams);
            return newState;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not gives any changes to the array

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you append the console.log output to your question?

Comment: Oh, you just forgot about coma after 1th `buttons` obj

Comment: The console.log output shows in the old state: 
buttons[0]: { id: 0, text: "asd", done: "false" }

In the new state: buttons[0]: { id: 0, text: "asd", done: "true" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168121/discussion-between-max-wolfen-and-rahamin).

Comment: Need to go back to my work :) Did my answer/comments help? Can you continue on your own?

Comment: Yes, now it work, I update my question. Thank you! But now I have a some strange in the props rerendering. See mu UPD question if you can

Comment: Sorry, I need to go back to my work... I suggest that you try to solve it, and if you don't succeed in the next hour or two, post a new question.