# passing object to update one field in an array in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to pass an object data to action which should then update one field in an array of objcts in redux state. I've found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628774/how-to-update-single-value-inside-specific-array-item-in-redux) which is pretty similar to my question but i cant quite figure how to apply it to my situation here. here's my code:

Here's my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  plfrm: {
    plfrm_collection: plfrm_collection,
    comment_collection: comment_collection,
    selected: [
      // {
      //     plfrm_selected_key: null,
      //     plfrm_selected_name: '',
      //     like: null,
      //     comment_selected: null
      // } 
      /* this should be the body of the selected object */
    ]
  }
}
export default function PaymentInfoReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PAYMENT_INFO_PARAMS_CHANGES_PLFRM:
      return update(state, {
        plfrm: {
          ...state.plfrm,
          selected: {
            [action.id]: update(...state.plfrm.selected[action.id], {
              $push: action.data
            })
          },
        },
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Here's my action:

```
export function plfrmChange(id, data) {
    return {
        type: PAYMENT_INFO_PARAMS_CHANGES_PLFRM,
        id,
        data
    }
}
```

And when i pass it from the component, im doing it like this:

```
plfrmChange = (key, field, value) => {
    if(this.isPlfrmSelected(key)){ //item ald selected, update the [field]
        console.log('found')
        this.props.plfrmChange(this.findSelectedPlfrmIndex(key), {
            [field]: value
        })
    } else { //item not selected yet, so add new [field]
        console.log('not found')
        if(this.props.plfrm.selected.length === 0){ //if no item in array yet, index will b 0
            this.props.plfrmChange(0, {
                [field]: value
            })
        } else { //otherwise index will equal to length of array
            this.props.plfrmChange(this.props.plfrm.selected.length, {
                [field]: value
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and when i run i got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
 60 | return update(state, {
  61 |     plfrm: {
  62 |         ...state.plfrm,
> 63 |         selected: {
  64 |             [action.id]: update(...state.plfrm.selected[action.id], {$push: action.data})
  65 |         },
  66 |     }
```

Im new to react, and i know my code is messy. Apology in advanced.

Comment: Can you use console.log to see what is the value of `state.plfrm.selected[action.id]` in your reducer?

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator (`...`) can only be updated to an object or an array.

In your initial state, `plfrm.selected` is an empty array. Therefore, when you try to access `state.plfrm.selected[action.id]` for the first time, it will be `undefined`. Since you apply the spread operator in line 64, you got the error. You could do something like this to resolve the issue.

```
...(state.plfrm.selected[action.id] || {})
```