# How to push item in specific index of and array of useState reactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

In this case I've and array by using useState

```
const [acts, setActs] = useState([])
```

now the point is that I want to push item at 4th index in array, and it should look like this

```
['', '', '', '' ,'should be here', '', '']
```

So, the method I'm trying to do this is here

```
let actsArray = []
const [acts, setActs] = useState(actsArray)

const addItem = (index) => {
   actsArray.splice(index, 0, 'Should be here')
   setActs(actsArray)
}
```

Comment: There's also this question about Redux, but the strategy is really similar: [How to update single value inside specific array item in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35628774/1218980)

Comment: Thanks for reference @Emile. I've got my problem solved!