# Adding a key to Object with React Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hoping this is a easy question but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm attempting to append a key to a object that is held in state. This key and value pair don't exist prior which I think is whats giving me the problem. Anyways here's what I have so far:

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_STUDENT_TAGS":
      const userID = action.payload.id;

      let studentIndex = state.originalStudentList.students.findIndex(obj => obj.id === action.payload.id);

      return {
      

        ...state,
            originalStudentList: {
                ...state.originalStudentList,
                students: {
                    [studentIndex]: {
                            tags: "test"
                    }
                }
            }
      };
```

Now the issue i'm running into is that I can run findIndex once but any attempt after just crashes my app saying its not a function. Simiarly the set state logic in the reducer there doesn't work either as it can't find "tags". So I guess i'm at a loss of how to do this. Here's how the data that is getting fed in looks:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      
      "id": "1",
      
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      
    }
  ]
}
```

here's the function from the input box:

```
const addTag = (event, student) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      if (event.target.value != "") {

        dispatch({
          type: "SET_STUDENT_TAGS",
          payload: {
            id: student.id,
            value: event.target.value,
          },
        });

        event.target.value = "";
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  };
```

what I'd like to achieve:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      
      "id": "1",
      "tags": ["cat", "dog"]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tags": ["cat", "parrot"]
    }
  ]
}
```

So i'm at a lost as to how to do this correctly. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but that syntax replaces the array with a regular object, which is why `findIndex` fails after the first time. For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56484856/11870335).

And then to add a property to the specific student, you just replace it with an object spreading the original and adding the tags:

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_STUDENT_TAGS":
      const userID = action.payload.id;

      let studentIndex = state.originalStudentList.students.findIndex(obj => obj.id === action.payload.id);
      let student = state.originalStudentList.students[studentIndex];

      return {
      

        ...state,
            originalStudentList: {
                ...state.originalStudentList,
                students: [
                    state.originalStudentList.students.slice(0, studentIndex),
                    {
                        ...student,
                      tags: action.payload.tags
                    },
                    state.originalStudentList.students.slice(studentIndex+1)
                ]
            }
      };
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so much :D